# Python add data to post body

Tags: python, rest, urllib2

I am struggling getting a Rest API Post to work with a vendor api and hope someone can give me a pointer.

The intent is to feed a cli command to the post body and pass to a device which returns the output.

The call looks like this : ( this works for all other calls but this is different because of posting to body)

```
  def __init__(self,host,username,password,sid,method,http_meth):
   self.host=host
   self.username= username
   self.password= password
   self.sid=sid
   self.method=method
   self.http_meth=http_meth

  def __str__(self):
   self.url = 'http://' + self.host + '/rest/'
   self.authparams = urllib.urlencode({ "session_id":self.sid,"method":  self.method,"username": self.username,
        "password": self.password,
    })

 call = urllib2.urlopen(self.url.__str__(), self.authparams).read()
 return (call)
```

No matter how I have tried this I cant get it to work properly. Here is an excerpt from the API docs that explains how to use this method:

To process these APIs, place your CLI commands in the HTTP post buffer, and then place the
method name, session ID, and other parameters in the URL.

Can anyone give me an idea of how to properly do this. I am not a developer and am trying to learn this correctly. For example if I wanted to send the command "help" in the post body?

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: You would probably be better off using the requests library http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html it works at a higher level than urllib and is easier to work with.

Comment: are your authentication parameters passed as part of the URL? I mean something like url?sessionid=...&...

Comment: I agree with Tom, use Requests, ditch urllib2

Comment: Yes authentication is part of the URL... Request does look much easier, so let me try to get it to work that way . I will post back with solution or if I get stuck again. Thanks for response.

Comment: ok I can seem to wrap my head around the proper way to do this even with requests . So I need to feed in authentication as a part of the URL (url?sessionid=...&...) and then I simply need to place a command "help" in the post body. I cant seem to figure it out as everything looks to require a dictionary object. Anybody have a simple example of how this could be done... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was ridiculously simple and I was over-thinking this. I find that I can sometimes look at a much higher level than a problem really is and waist time. Anyway this is how it should work:

```
   def cli(self,method):
     self.url = ("http://" + str(self.host) + "/rest//?method=" +str(method)+ "&username=" +str(self.username)+ "&password=" +str(self.password)+ "&enable_password=test&session_id="+str(self.session_id))
     data="show ver"
     try:
      req = urllib2.Request(self.url)
      response = urllib2.urlopen(req,data)
      result = response.read()
      print result

     except urllib2.URLError, e:
      print e.reason
```

The cli commands are just placed in the buffer and not encoded....